# Expected value Holder inequality

Tags: inequality, random-variables, expected-value, holder-inequality

I have the following question; how do you prove this statement? I know that it is probably something related to the Holder inequality, but I couldn't figure out how to use it in this case.

Let $p,q > 0$ be such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Consider the real valued random variables $X, Y, Z$ that satisfy the following
\begin{align}
|Z| \leq |X|^{\frac{1}{p}} |Y|^\frac{1}{q} 
\end{align}
Prove that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|Z|^q] \leq \mathbb{E} \left[ |X|^{\frac{q}{p}} \right] \mathbb{E} \left[|Y| \right] 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\mathbb{E}[|Z|^q] \leq \mathbb{E}\bigl[|X|^{q/p}|Y|\bigr]
= \mathbb{E}\bigl[|X|^{q/p}\bigr] \mathbb{E}[|Y|] + \mathrm{cov}\bigl(|X|^{q/p},|Y|\bigr)
\leq \mathbb{E}\bigl[|X|^{q/p}\bigr] \mathbb{E}[|Y|]
$$
if $\mathrm{cov}\bigl(|X|^{q/p},|Y|\bigr) \leq 0$. This is the case for instance if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

In general, the inequality is not true. Consider $X=Y=Z \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ and $p=q=2$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}[|Z|^2] = \frac12 > \frac14 =
\mathbb{E}[|X|]\mathbb{E}[|Y|].
$$